# Value Object as @AggregateIdentifier and @TargetAggregateIdentifier

Tags: spring, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

First I apologize for the very long post. There is quite some code to be showed to have a detailed understanding of the problem hence lost of stuff to post... Please be so kind to read all of it :-)

I am trying to develop a event sourcing based application using the Axon framework together with a Spring Boot application. I provided a number of class definitions bellow making up the aggregate, command and event implementations.

I wrote a very simple test application (Spring) which does no more than sending a CreateAppointmentCommand to Axon. This create command uses a manually assigned AppointmentId (which is a subclass a AbstractId) and returns this ID for later use. Nothing wrong with that, the constructor command handler in Appointment is called as expected and the corresponding ApppointmentCreatedEvent is fired and also handled as expected by the Appoitment class. So far, so good. 
The problem arises when I send a ConfirmAppointmentCommand with the ID returned by the create command. Under these circumstances I receive an error message :

> Command 'ConfirmAppointmentCommand' resulted in org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandExecutionException(Provided id of the wrong type for class Appointment. Expected: class AppointmentId, got class java.lang.String)

I don't understand a few things in this setup related to this error message:

1. Why do the create command and event work as expected while they are using the same approach (at least to my understanding so far) compared to the confirm command/event?
2. Why is Axon complaining about an AppointmentId as the identifier for (asumably the aggregate) while the corresponding code (see below) annotates both String types for the @AggregateIdentier and the @TargetAggregateIdentier?
3. Am I allowed to store an aggregate directly to a persistent store using the same code for both the aggregate and the entity (in this case a JPA repository managed by Spring and linked to a relational database) while being used by Axon (I don't think I should use the State-Stored Aggregates approach described in the reference guide because I still want my solution to be event driven for the creating and updating of appointments)?
4. Is this the correct approach to keep the state of the aggregate up to date using the event mechanism and is it ok to have a different Spring @Component class which is implementing a series of @EventHandler methods to do the CRUD operations toward the relational database. In the latter, the create event is handled as expected an the appointment gets stored in the database. The confirm events are not being triggered due to the previous error message.
5. Refering to item 4 I am a bit confused about what will happen if Axon is restarted and starts emitting the different events to the event handler in 4. Won't this result in a lot of database errors because the appointment are still in place in the database, or in the worst case endless duplicates of the same appointments? In other words, there seems to be something wrong with the approach I am using in this project and in my understanding of event driven applications/services.

Please check to different class definitions below for more detailled information. First I have the root aggregate Appointment which will be used as JPA entity at the same time.

```
@Aggregate
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_appointment")
public final class Appointment extends AbstractEntity<AppointmentId> {

    //JPA annotated class members left out for brevity

    @PersistenceConstructor
    private Appointment() {
        super(null);
        //Sets all remaining class members to null.
    }

    @CommandHandler
    private Appointment(CreateAppointmentCommand command) {
        super(command.getAggregateId());
        validateFields(getEntityId(), ...);
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new AppointmentCreatedEvent(getEntityId(), ...);
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    private void on(AppointmentCreatedEvent event) {
        validateFields(event.getAggregateId(), ...);
        initFields(event.getAggregateId(), ...);
    }

    private void validateFields(AppointmentId appointmentId, ...) {
        //Check if all arguments are within the required boundaries.
    }

    private void initFields(AppointmentId appointmentId, ...) {
        //Set all class level variables to passed in value.
    }

    @CommandHandler
    private void handle(ConfirmAppointmentCommand command) {
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new AppointmentConfirmedEvent(command.getAggregateId()));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    private void on(AppointmentConfirmedEvent event) {
        confirm();
    }

    public void confirm() {
        changeState(State.CONFIRMED);
    }   

    //Similar state changing command/event handlers left out for brevity.

    private void changeState(State newState) {
        switch (state) {
        ...
        }
    }

    //All getter methods left out for brevity. The aggregate does NOT provide any setters.

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Appointment [...]";
    }
}
```

The AbstractEntity class is a base class for all JPA entities and aggregates. This class has the following definition.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class AbstractEntity<ENTITY_ID extends AbstractId> implements Serializable{

    @EmbeddedId
    private ENTITY_ID entityId;

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String targetId;


    protected AbstractEntity(ENTITY_ID id) {
        this.LOG = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());
        this.entityId = id;
        this.targetId = id != null ? id.getId() : null;
    }

    public final ENTITY_ID getEntityId() {
        return entityId;
    }

    @Override
    public final int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((entityId == null) ? 0 : entityId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        AbstractEntity<?> other = (AbstractEntity<?>) obj;
        if (entityId == null) {
            if (other.entityId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!entityId.equals(other.entityId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

The entityId (which will be used as the primary key for the JPA entities) is a 'complex' value object having the following base class definition.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class AbstractId implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;


    protected AbstractId() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public final String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public final int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        AbstractId other = (AbstractId) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public final String toString() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Within the aggregate, a number of commands and events are used. Each command is a subclass of Command.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class Command<AGGREGATE_ID extends AbstractId> implements Serializable{

    private AGGREGATE_ID aggregateId;

    @TargetAggregateIdentifier
    private String targetId;

    protected Command(AGGREGATE_ID aggregateId) {
        if(aggregateId == null) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(...);
        }   
        this.aggregateId = aggregateId;
        this.targetId = aggregateId != null ? aggregateId.getId() : null;
    }

    public final AGGREGATE_ID getAggregateId() {
        return aggregateId;
    }   
}
```

A specified command class (which causes difficulties in my approach) is the ConfirmAppointmentCommand which is actually no more than a concrete implementation of the base Command class. The implementation is therefore very straight forward.

```
public final class ConfirmAppointmentCommand extends Command<AppointmentId> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6618106729289153342L;

    public ConfirmAppointmentCommand(AppointmentId appointmentId) {
        super(appointmentId);       
    }   
}
```

The CreateAppointmentCommand is very similar to the ConfirmAppointmentCommand and is defined as follows.

```
public final class CreateAppointmentCommand extends Command<AppointmentId> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5445719522854349344L;

    //Some additional class members left out for brevity.

    public CreateAppointmentCommand(AppointmentId appointmentId, ...) {
        super(appointmentId);

        //Check to verify the provided method arguments are left out.

        //Set all verified class members to the corresponding values.
    }

    //Getters for all class members, no setters are being implemented.

}
```

For the different events used in the project, a similar approach is used. All events subclass a base DomainEvent class as defined below.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public abstract class DomainEvent<T extends AbstractId> implements Serializable{

        private T aggregateId;


        protected DomainEvent(T aggregateId) {
            if(aggregateId == null) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(ErrorCodes.AGGREGATE_ID_MISSING);
            }           
            this.aggregateId = aggregateId;
        }

        public final T getAggregateId() {
            return aggregateId;
        }   
    }
```

The AppointmentCreatedEvent is pretty straight forward.

```
public final class AppointmentCreatedEvent extends DomainEvent<AppointmentId> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5265970306200850734L;

    //Class members left out for brevity

    public AppointmentCreatedEvent(AppointmentId appointmentId, ...) {
        super(appointmentId);

        //Check to verify the provided method arguments are left out.

        //Set all verified class members to the corresponding values.
    }

    //Getters for all class members, no setters are being implemented.
}
```

And finally for completeness, the AppointmentConfirmedEvent.

```
public final class AppointmentConfirmedEvent extends DomainEvent<AppointmentId> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5415394808454635999L;

    public AppointmentConfirmedEvent(AppointmentId appointmentId) {
        super(appointmentId);       
    }
}
```

Few, you made it until the end of the post. Thanks for that in the first please!
Could you please advise me about where things are going wrong or what I am doing wrong?

Greatful regards,
Kurt

Comment: Hi, a long post indeed. I noticed you even left some things out to make it shorter. Unfortunately, I think the key to your problem is where it now says "//JPA annotated class members left out for brevity". Could you at least add the `@Id` and `@AggregateIdentifier` annotated fields? The rest of the fields doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. `@Id` isn't explicitly used in the entity because I want to use an object (the real identifier of the entity is wrapped as a value object, e.g. ApppointmentId) as the "provider" for the JPA id. Therefor the AbstractEntity class has a `@EmbeddedId` annotated field instead of a `@Id` annotated field. The same AbstractEntity class also contains a field as the `@AggregateIdentifier`. Since Appointment inherits AbstractEntity, both field should be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 3**
From your third question I notice you **do not** want to use Axon's State-Stored Aggregate approach, but Event Sourcing instead. On the other hand, you **are** storing the Aggregate as a state object too by making it an entity.

What is your intent with this? If this is to use the `Appointment` to be returned to interested parties, than you should know that you are not following CQRS on that matter.

The `@Aggregate` annotated class within Axon typically points towards the Command Model. It's thus purely used to ingest commands, decide whether that command's expression of intent can be performed  and publish events as a result to this.

Added, you state you are putting this in a Spring Boot application. 
From there I am assuming you are using the `axon-spring-boot-starter` dependency as well. When using Axon's Spring auto configuration, the `@Aggregate` works as a "Spring Stereotype". On top of this if the `@Aggregate` annotated object is **also** annotated with `@Entity`, than the auto configuration assumes you want to store the Aggregate as-is. Thus, it'll default to having a State-Stored Aggregate; something you state isn't what you want.

**Questions 1 and 2**
The create command is likely working as this is the initiation point of the Aggregate. Hence, it isn't retrieving an existing format based on an identifier yet.

Secondly, the exception you receive, although wrapped in a `CommandExecutionException`, originally comes from likely your database. Doing a quick search for the text `Provided id of the wrong type for class` in Axon's code base doesn't lead to anything. 
Note that Axon will assume ID's to be convertible to `String` always. Hence a dedicated `toString()` method can be beneficial to not append undesired information to the `String`.

It's this part where Allard is asking more info about, as it's likely to do with the fact that the Aggregate in essence is State-Stored right now. Thus, the exception bubbles up from the JPA implementation used by the `GenericJpaRepository` (it's this repo. which Axon auto configures for you given the current set up) for the given Aggregate.

**Questions 4 and 5**
It is indeed completely fine to update your Aggregate through `@EventSourcingHandler` annotated methods and have a distinct Spring Component within your application which handles the events to update projections. I'd regard this as "the way to go" when doing CQRS through Axon.

The last concern you're having requires me to make an assumption. I am guessing you haven't configured anything specific around the [Event Processor](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/event-processing/event-processors) being used. This means Axon will auto configure a `TrackingEventProcessor` for you. One of the things this implementation does is store it's progress of "how far it is with handling events in the event stream" in a Token. These tokens should in turn be stored alongside your projections, as they define how up-to-date your projections are when it comes to the entire event stream.

If you notice that the event handlers from within the Event Handling Component to be called every time on start up, that to me signals that the `token_entry` table is either not there or it's being cleared on every start up.

**Concluding**
Quite a mouthful here, definitely hope this helps you out Kurt!
If anything is unclear, please comment on my answer; I'll update my response accordingly.

Comment: **Question 3** My intent is to "register" the creation and modification of appointments as a series of events in the event sourcing system. The entity would be used to maintain an easy accessible last state of all events related to the same appointmentId. This entity will be made accessible using a Spring repository to a REST services. To reduce the amount of code written, the idea was to use the same POJO as both the aggregate (for handling event sourcing) and the entity (for the most recent state).

Indeed I do use the `axon-spring-boot-starter` dependency.

Comment: **Question 1 & 2** Sounds very plausible. I split the aggregate and the entity in separated classes with a base super class containing the class members and the different getters. The aggregate sub class contains the `@AggregateIdentifier` together with the command handlers and the event sourcing handlers. The entity sub class contains the `@Id` annotation. Now everything seems to work without the previous exception and no complaints about the value object type used as aggregate and entity id. Although this approach works, it feel wrong to do so. Am I missing a point here about Axon/CQRS/ES?

Comment: **Question 4 & 5** Your assumption is right! No specific configurations added around EventProcessor. I do actually see event handling methods being called on each start up. Since all appointment data is stored as events, the appointment table is built up on application start. I suppose it could be beneficial to use an in memory database to store the appointment query data. The difficulty for my use case in this is not all application data is stored as events. I also have a table containing customer data for which (I suppose) there is little added value in making this event sourcing based?

Comment: I really appreciate the extensive amount of information you provide in your answer. It is without any doubt very helpful information. Perhaps the biggest problem is currently the limited experience I have with CQRS and event sourcing systems. Please feel free to point-out things I misunderstand or interpret the wrong way... Any feedback will be greatly appreciated! 
Hope everything is safe and sound for the both (Steven and Allard) of you in the Netherlands.

Comment: Thanks for the concern @KDW, but Allard and I are indeed still safe and sound in the Netherlands. :-) When it comes to your responses:
Q1, 2 & 3: Gotcha, the intent was to minimize duplication. Having segregated classes, one as the Query Model (your `@Entity`) and another as the Command Model (your `@Aggregate`) would indeed resolve this I think.
Q4 & 5: Using an in memory database would still mean you'd see your models being replayed! What you'd need to use is a dedicated `TokenStore`. In a Spring Boot app, having JPA or JDBC on the classpath will make this part auto configured too.

Comment: So, are there still some missing links in my answer? Would you expect me to update some portions for clarity?

By the way, what might be interesting for you is the "Fast Lane Axon Framework" webinar AxonIQ is currently giving at a monthly bases -> https://axoniq.io/event-overview
It will explain DDD, CQRS and Event Sourcing, in conjunction with Axon, in a 2 hour session. Added, you will have the opportunity to ask us questions. :-)

Comment: Using segregated classes indeed solves the issue with the mentionned error message. I guess I'm being punisched for trying to be to lazy ;-). 
I also decided not to use an in-memory store which resolves the replay issue. Thanks for the tip about the 2 hour session :-) Up to next steps in the project...

Comment: Happy to hear all this helped you out @KDW!